# How to check prime number using user-defined function?

Tags: c

I know what a prime number is. But I am unable to solve the logic using C. I tried as below:

```
main()
{
    int a, b, c, n=0, start, end, sum=0;
    printf("Range Start From: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("End of Range: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    for(a=start;a<=end;a++)
    {
        for(b=2;b<=a/2;b++)
        {
            if(a%b==0)
            {
                c=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(c==1)
        {
            sum+=a;
            n++;
        }
    }
    printf("The Sum of Primes is: %d\nTotal primes: %d", sum, n);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled would have caught this problem immediately:  `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` is your friend.

Comment: Try to insert the code " c=1;  " before the code " for(b=2;b<=a/2;b++); "!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: In your inner loop, you have your failure case:

```
if(a%b==0)
{
    c=0;
    break;
}
```

And then you check for a success case:

```
if(c==1)
{
    sum+=a;
    n++;
}
```

But when does `c` become `1`?

Comment: The problem is not the break! The break is what she wants, the problem is the uninitialized variable c!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I never said the problem was the break...

Comment: Excuse me, I understood in a wrong way your reply!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following code to have a little bit of speed.

```
if ( !(a&1) && a!=2) { // !(a&1) is true if a is an even number!
    c=0;
} else {
   c=1; //This is the initialization that lacks in your code!
   for(b=3;b<=a/2;b+=2) 
   {
        if(a%b==0)
        {
          c=0;
         break;
        }
   }
}
```

This code doesn't consider 1 is a prime number as in your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Here is a sample:


 main()
 {
int a, b, c=1, n=0, start, end, sum=0;

printf("Range Start From: ");

scanf("%d", &start);
printf("End of Range: ");
scanf("%d", &end);
for(a=start;a<=end;a++)
 {
    for(b=2;b<=a/2;b++)
    {
        if(a%b==0)
    {
     c=0;
    break;
    }
   if(c==1) printf("%d  ", a);
   c=1;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written this code that is based on the fact that prime numbers are always represented by one of the functions p=k*6-1 or p=k*6+1, but not all the results of these two functions are prime. This code also has the capability to use a table of primes. (To use the table you have to compile this code with the option -DUSE_A_TABLE and you have to write the code to initialize it).

I think you can use easily the function isPrime, The isPrime function will result faster if you activate the primes table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef USE_A_TABLE
uint64_t *primi=NULL;
uint64_t inTable=0;
#endif

int isPrime(uint64_t n);

int isPrime(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t m,k,i;

    if (!n)
        return 0;

    if (n<4 || n==5)
        return 1;

    if (!(n&1))
        return 0;

    if (!(n%3))
        return 0;

    k=(n-1)/6;m=(n+1)/6;
    if (k*6+1 != n && m*6-1 != n)
        return 0;

    m=sqrt(n)+1;
#ifdef USE_A_TABLE
    k=5;
    for (i=3;i<inTable && primi[i]<=m;i++) {
        k=primi[i];
        if (!(n%k))
            return 0;
    }
    k+=2;

    k=(k-1)/6;
#else
    k=1;
#endif

    m=(m+1)/6;
    for (i=k; i<=m; i++) {
        if ( !(n%(6*i-1)) || !(n%(6*i+1)) )
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t from=1;
    uint64_t to=10000;
    uint64_t n;

    for(n=from;n<=to;n++) {
        if (isPrime(n))
            printf("%5lu",n);
    }
    puts("");

    from=400000000;
    to=400002000;

    for(n=from;n<=to;n++) {
        if (isPrime(n))
            printf("%10lu",n);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```